# How to store a set of values of same type related to one item in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I an new to programming and I just started creating a project in which users can post text and they can get likes for that data,

Now my doubt is that if there is post with id = 2 and 10 people like it. 
Then how can I store the Id of those 10 users for this single post,  in to a database.

That is how will I store details of all users liking that post,  for each post into a database, .

Comment: You have a users table with a user_id. You have a posts table with a post_id. You have a user_likes_post table with a user_id and a post_id. Does that already answer your question?

Comment: Thanks,  it is simple,  my problem was that didn't think at all and just posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an 1:n relation. A post can be liked by 0, 1 or more people and a like is related to a single post. A user can have 0, 1 or more likes, but a like was done by a given user. As a result, you have your `posts` table, with a given `id` column, a `users` table with a given `id` column and a `likes` table, which should have a foreign key to the `users` table to make sure you will know who issued the like and a foreign key to the `posts` table to make sure you will know to which post the like belongs.

Comment: @rranj Make sure that a unique key exists between posts and user for the like, otherwise you'll allow the same user to Like something hundreds of times and artificially increase the count... but maybe you want that behavior!

Comment: @rranj, you are welcome. If this answers your question, then you might consider accepting it to let others know that this is the right answer.